# Dynamically generate Eureka Form Rows

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

Is there a way to build eureka forms from a json/api response. So far i've been able to convert to json returned to an object. But having issues creating a for loop to generate the form.

```
form
+++ Section("API Returns")

for values in JSONObject{

    <<< TextRow() {
        $0.tag = values.key
        $0.title = values.name
        $0.value = values.value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to indicate which Section the TextRow is going to be inserted to inside your loop.

```
let section = Section("API Returns")
form +++ section

for values in JSONObject{

    section <<< TextRow() {
        $0.tag = values.key
        $0.title = values.name
        $0.value = values.value
    }
}
```

You also use this assuming your "API Returns" section is the last section of your form.

```
for values in JSONObject {

    guard let section = self.form.last else {
        return
    }

    section <<< TextRow() {
        $0.tag = values.key
        $0.title = values.name
        $0.value = values.value
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, would this not create a new section on every new value returned from the API?

Comment: No it will not, you are not using +++ section inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
for values in JSONObject {

    guard let section = self.form.last else {
        return
    }

    section <<< TextRow() {
        $0.tag = values.key
        $0.title = values.name
        $0.value = values.value
    }
}
form
+++ section(){...}
```